# Get distinct values from a column in a single comma separated string in sql?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that has rows that contains data for the same address from different sources-

| RowID | Address | Source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Addr1 | Src 1 |
| 1 | Addr1 | Src 2 |
| 1 | Addr1 | Src 3 |

What I want to achieve -

| RowID | Address | Source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Addr1 | Src 1, Src2, Src3 |

I am using snowflake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ou can use `listagg` to achieve it.

If ou need a special order, you need to add following after the listagg

```
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sortcolumn DESC)
```

The query without ordering is

```
SELECT
    RowID,  Address, listagg(Source, ', ')
FROM table1
GROUP BY RowID  Address
```